# Should I prefer Boost or the C++11 standard library, if I'm already using Boost?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

In my project I'm using `boost::asio` for networking and thread management. I would like to use some features of modern C++, for example shared pointers.

There are two choices: `boost::shared_ptr`, since I'm already using Boost, and `std::shared_ptr` since I'm using a C++11 compiler. As far as I understand those are basically equivalent, however they are incompatible with each other.

I've read that I should prefer the standard library components over Boost, to not use an external dependency pointlessly. However I will still be using Boost (at least until and if they decide to integrate ASIO into the standard library), so I still require that dependency.

Shared pointers are just an example, this question applies to all features that the standard library took over from Boost, such as `function`, `bind`, `thread`, etc.

Given my situation, which is the preferred implementation of the feature? Are there any gotchas regarding the choice, where I would be required to use either the Boost or standard library version specifically, when using some of the other Boost or standard library components?

Comment: what would be a reason to use the boost alternative when you can get the same from the standard lib? I dont know any

Comment: Opinion based? Perhaps I'm a dogmatic old cat, but the opposing opinion to mine has no validity. Therefore an answer is concrete.

Comment: If an opinion about using a standard is a standard opinion, should it not simply be a standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although Boost is the de facto feeder for future C++ standards, is it *not* standardised so you always are at the mercy of compatibility breaks if you choose Boost over the C++ standard library. (See the historic breaking changes to Boost Spirit for an example).

Therefore, always code with a view to migrating to the C++ standard library whenever possible.

Compiler optimisations can also be more readily made with C++ standard library functions too, since their precise behaviour is defined by the standard.